# flutter: match list value to map list key value

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, key

newbie here. would anyone know how can i match the value of list x to the value of list y's key["id"]?

thank you in advance! appreciate any help. =)

```
list x = ["open_box", "close_box"];
list y = 
[
    {
        "id": "open_box",
        "name": "Open",
        "action": ["open_box"]
    },
    {
        "id": "close_box",
        "name": "Close",
        "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box"]
    },
    {
        "id": "pull_box",
        "name": "Pull",
        "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box", "push_box"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

loop through **x** using for in, and then finally you can use **where** method from List

```
for (String action in x) {
  dynamic temp = y.where((data) => data['id'] == action);
  if (temp.isNotEmpty) {
    // do someting
    print(temp);
  }
}
```

Ref: [Dart Documentation - List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.5/dart-core/List-class.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
    list x = ["open_box", "close_box"];
    list y = 
    [
        {
            "id": "open_box",
            "name": "Open",
            "action": ["open_box"]
        },
        {
            "id": "close_box",
            "name": "Close",
            "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box"]
        },
        {
            "id": "pull_box",
            "name": "Pull",
            "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box", "push_box"]
        }
    ];
    var i,j;
    var yy=jsonDecode(y);
for(j=0;j<=x.length;j++){
    for(i=0;i<=yy.length;i++){

    if(yy[i]['id'].contains(x[j])){
    
    //Do something if true
    print(yy[i]);
    
    }
    }
}
```

This code compare **x[0]** means "open_box" to all **List of Maped data of y** it will print index value where conditions true

Answer (score 1):

List provides a [where](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/where.html) method that allows you to filter the list based on a condition. Here I am using the `where` method of the `y` list and searching the `x` list for the `id` value of the current item in the `y` list. I check the length of the search for the `x` list and if it is greater than zero, then we have found a match inside the `x` list for that `id`. `z` will hold the list of items that have matched the ids from the `x` list inside the `y` list.

```
List x = ["open_box", "close_box"];
List y = 
[
        {
                "id": "open_box",
                "name": "Open",
                "action": ["open_box"]
        },
        {
                "id": "close_box",
                "name": "Close",
                "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box"]
        },
        {
                "id": "pull_box",
                "name": "Pull",
                "action": ["open_box", "close_box", "pull_box", "push_box"]
        }
];
var z = y.where((data) => x.where((value) => value==data["id"]).length>0);
print(z);
```

Here is the expected output

```
I/flutter ( 6086): ({id: open_box, name: Open, action: [open_box]}, {id: close_box, name: Close, action: [open_box, close_box, pull_box]})
```